# Memory usage with table view with different cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So my case is this - I have a table view and depending on the data I get back from my backend I want to draw different cells. So one table view can have cell Type A and cell Type B.

The way I've done this right now, which is causing a lot of memory issues is like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([self.resultsTuples count] != 0){
    NSDictionary* rowData = self.resultsTuples[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* tableCell = [self.resultTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    UIView* cardView = [cardChooser getCardView:rowData];
    [tableCell.contentView addSubview:cardView];
    return tableCell;
} else {
    return nil;

}
return nil;
```

}

I then return the correct view -

```
-(UIView*)getCardView:(NSDictionary*) component{
if(condition1){
    return [ self getListResultView: component];
} else if (condiiton2){

    return [self getEventResultView: component];
} else if (condition3){

    return [self getProductResultView: component];
} else {
    return [self getGeneralResultView: component];
}
return nil;
```

}

There are a number of issues here - the view controller goes out of scope, so the views should not work(it only works now I think because the view controller has not been overwritten yet). Further, because I'm using addSubview the retain count goes up and those views are lying around, so my memory usage keeps going up.

Right now I have a bunch of view controllers that init xib files. One way I thought of getting around this was to have instance variables of those view controllers in the table view controller and then set the fields on those view controllers in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

However, I would still have to do addSubview and I think those memory issues will persist.

How should I get around this?

EDIT-
    An idea I had was to have one custom table view that is drawn differently based on every condition...the problem with this is what if I have 50 custom cells? Then I suddenly have a view with a ton of drawing code that is hard to read.

Comment: FYI - you can't return `nil` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If that code is reached your app will crash. You also keep adding `cardView` subviews to a cell if it is reused. That's bad.

Comment: I know...I posted this question because I realize that it's bad and I want to know what I should do

Comment: Don't keep adding `cardView` instances. Only add it if the cell doesn't already have one.

Comment: ok...how does the cell know that it has a card view instance?

Comment: Give the cardView a tag then see if the contentView has a subview with that tag or not. If not, add the new cardView.

Comment: I am using ARC. @rmaddy - then how should the info on each card view be updated? the cardView is an UIView, but each sub controller is returning a view of a different type

Comment: You get a reference to the existing cardView and update it as needed for the given row.

Comment: @praks5432 How do you determine which data requires which cell? What is it based on? Also are you storing your data in an array or dictionary? Tis is a simple problem with a simple solution but my explanation will get messy if i dont know in advance how youre managing your dAta source. Pleased do update your post explaining how you are managing your data soon as it comes from the back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isSupposedToBeCellTypeA = YES;

    // here you'll want to determine if you want cell type A or B....
    BOOL isSupposedToBeCellTypeA = .......

    // if you want A
    if (isSupposedToBeCellTypeA) {
        // attempt to dequeue a cell of that type
        CellTypeA *cellA = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellA"];

        // if you can't reuse one, create it
        if (cellA != nil) {
            cellA = [[CellTypeA alloc] init];
        }

        // customize the cell however you need to here...
        cellA.title = @"This is a cell of type A";

        // then return it
        return cellA;
    }

    // otherwise you want B
    else {
        // attempt to dequeue a cell of that type
        CellTypeB *cellB = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellB"];

        // if you can't reuse one, create it
        if (cellB != nil) {
            cellB = [[CellTypeA alloc] init];
        }

        // customize the cell however you need to here...
        cellB.title = @"This is a cell of type B";

        // then return it
        return cellB;
    }
}
```

Do whatever logic you need to based on the indexPath and your data source to determine which type of cell you need to create FIRST, then once you've done that all it takes is a simple if statement to be able to implement the reuse/dequeue code and creation/return of the appropriate cells. This is all assuming you've subclassed the cells and created your own custom cells? Without knowing a bit more information about the specifics, I don't know if I can give you a better answer.

Comment: yup - I did exactly this - so right now when I do this the simulator seems to add a shadow to every component of my custom view - why is that?

Comment: Without looking at the code that generates your views I wouldn't be able to say. If I took a look at it I might be able to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070639/shadow-is-being-added-to-custom-uitableviewcell

Comment: If my original answer was helpful in solving your original problem, marking it as the accepted answer would be greatly appreciated. I'm taking a look at your code now to see if I can help with this second issue.

Comment: well I guess I'm not sure if I should accept it because I came up with that solution before I read your answer - what's the etiquette on situations like this?

Comment: I would think that accepting my answer would make it easy for anyone who comes across your question to see what the solution was, even if you arrived at it on your own. I did take the time to write a detailed explanation and provide the code to answer your question.